# Same query method and parameters with different return in Spring Data

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to use projections in order to return less elements for the same queries.

```
Page<Network> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids);
Page<NetworkSimple> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids);
```

Since the queries are created using the name of the method, what options do I have to do the same query but with different name ?

Comment: Spring Data query via method is constructed by convention and you can't change the name and yet expecting a same behavior.
Are you open to use @Query annotations which doesn't depend on the method name, or possibly implementing custom DAO using JPAQuery. S

Comment: @vine yes, I can use the Query annotation, and probably should be the best solution for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: will create an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data query via method is constructed by convention and you can't change the name and yet expecting a same behavior.

You can try to use @Query annotations which doesn't depend on the method name, or possibly implementing custom DAO using JPAQuery plus FactoryExpression which has the same effect as projections.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this today, and the accepted answer is actually incorrect; you *can* change the method name without altering the behavior. According to the Spring Data documentation:

> Any text between find (or other introducing keywords) and By is considered to be descriptive unless using one of the result-limiting keywords such as a Distinct to set a distinct flag on the query to be created or Top/First to limit query results.

Thus you can have a method named `findByIdIn` and another named `findNetworkSimpleByIdIn` and the two will return the same data (optionally converted to a different form depending on the defined return type).