# Return different Dto using same repository method with Spring Boot repositories

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I have two DTOs
One for a get method like "/pessoas/{id}"
And another one for "/pessoas/{id}/detalhes" where I am going to see more attributes of Pessoa.

My codes are in Kotlin.

My simple DTO:

```
interface PessoaDTO {
    val idInstitucional: UUID?
    val nome: String?
}

data class PessoaDTOImpl(override val idInstitucional: UUID?, override val nome: String?): PessoaDTO
```

My DTO with details:

```
interface PessoaDetalhesDTO {
    val idInstitucional: UUID?
    val nome: String?
    val email: String?
    val telefone: String?
    val cpf: Long?
}

data class PessoaDetalhesDTOImpl(override val idInstitucional: UUID?, override val nome: String?, override val email: String?, override val telefone: String?, override val cpf: Long?): PessoaDetalhesDTO
```

I have a repository that will be accessed by my PessoaController. I was thinking about having two methods in my Repository, each one for a different DTO.

That's my Repository:

```
internal interface PessoaRepository : CrudRepository<Pessoa, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutorWithProjection<Pessoa> {
    fun findByIdInstitucional(idInstitucional: UUID): PessoaDTO?
    fun findByIdInstitucional(idInstitucional: UUID): PessoaDetalhesDTO?
}
```

However, I can't have two functions with the same name in the Repository for different returned data types. 
How can I deal with that without having to create another Repository for the detailed information of Pessoa?

Comment: Probably this will answer to your question  -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548298/same-query-method-and-parameters-with-different-return-in-spring-data

Comment: You can use queries or native queries, the methods in the repository can then have different names with different return types without creating another repository